# Replace one square bracket and new line in all files using Shell script

Tags: sed

I know many similar questions exist, but I couldn't figure this particular pattern out and hence posting here (after spending lot of time and giving up). Please help :)

There's a string that I need to match and replace in all files in a given directory.

What it looks:

```
tag: 
  ["https://example.com"]
```

What it should be converted to:

```
tag: "https://example.com"
```

I need to match the patterns: **tag \n  [** and **"]** and replace them from all files.

This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
find . -type f -name "*.md" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/tag: \\n  \[\"/tag: /g'

find . -type f -name "*.md" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/\"\]/\"/g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e '/^tag: $/!b' -e '$b' -e 'N;s/\n *\["/"/;s/"]/"/' file
```

Tip: don't use `-i` until edits are correct.

Comment: This is magic. Thank you so much! Your answer saved my day and also my tomorrow as this would've taken me much longer to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^tag:\s*$/{N;s/\s*\n\s*\[("[^]]*")\]/ \1/;P;D}' file
```

If a line starts `tag:` and is followed by `["..."]` remove any spaces and the newline between the two strings and replace by the quoted string which is within the second string.

N.B. If the second line does not contain `["..."]` the first line will be printed and the second line will be accepted as the first line.